# a11y-profile-manager messed up the appearance of my desktop

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments

I typed: ***a11y-profile-manager*** into the terminal because I wanted to know what it does.

It put the Universal Access into the topbar.
Changed the cursor's and the text's size.
Changed my background and cursor icons.

Everything looks terrible now and I want my original desktop outlook back.
How can I get it back?
(I am using gnome-shell as my desktop enviroment)

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you on?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: Try with `a11y-profile-manager -d` ([source](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/a11y-profile-manager.1.html)). BTW a good way to know what things do without breaking your system is reading the documentation

Comment: I write it as an answer, please then accept it since it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
a11y-profile-manager -d
```

([source](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/a11y-profile-manager.1.html)).

In any case, a good way to know what things do without breaking your system is reading the documentation **before** doing it.